# How to register an enum with the GObject type module in python?

Tags: python, pygtk, pygobject

I'm trying to port some existing Perl code to Python:

```
package My::Package;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk3 -init;

BEGIN {
    Glib::Type->register_enum( 'My::Package::Enum', qw(value_one value_two) );
}

use Glib::Object::Subclass Gtk3::Window::,
  properties => [
    Glib::ParamSpec->enum('my_enum', 'nick', 'blurb', 'My::Package::Enum', 'value_one', [qw/readable writable/]),
  ];

package main;

my $window = My::Package->new;
print $window->get('my_enum'), "\n";
```

I've got this python code:

```
import gi
from gi.repository import GObject
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

GObject.TypeModule.register_enum( 'MyPackageEnum', ["value_one","value_two"] )

class MyPackage(Gtk.Window):
    my_enum=GObject.Property(type=MyPackageEnum,default='value_one',nick='nick',blurb='blurb')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

window = MyPackage()
print(window.get_property('my_enum'))
```

Which produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_enum.py", line 6, in <module>
    GObject.TypeModule.register_enum( 'MyPackageEnum', ["value_one","value_two"] )
TypeError: GObject.TypeModule.register_enum() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I'm guessing [I'm missing a self](https://pygobject-doc.gitee.io/pgi-docs/GObject-2.0/classes/TypeModule.html#GObject.TypeModule.register_enum).

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: If you insert `Gtk` as first argument to `register_enum()` you get error `TypeError: argument self: Expected GObject.TypeModule, but got gi.overrides.GtkProxyModule`... So the first argument should be a `GObject.TypeModule`

Comment: Yup. I also tried ```GObject.TypeModule().register_enum( 'MyPackageEnum', ["value_one","value_two"] )```, but got ```TypeError: cannot create instance of abstract (non-instantiable) type `GTypeModule'```

Comment: There seems to be an open issue on Gitlab tracking this: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/-/issues/215